# How to update sqlmap

Tags: updates

How to update sqlmap automatic SQL injection tool?

Comment: How did you install it originally?

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 15.10 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade sqlmap
```